# Monodroid Custom UI controls

Tags: user-interface, customization, xamarin.android

I want to know where I can get access to the NinePatch images specifically for Monodroid. I want to change the default coloring from blue to orange (if I was doing this in Java it would already be orange).

All I need is to change an edittext so that it's default colors are different. I have seen 
http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget
which is really helpful but only as far as vanilla Android is concerned. I tried following the instructions, but I found the standard orange java images, not the Mono ones, which are blue.

Minimum framework is 2.2. I know that I am getting the java images because when I go to C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms there is no android-2.2 folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer - and thank goodnesss it did not involve changing the 9Patches!

You can make an xml in the drawable folder which describes your button, textbox, etc. and make a selector with a solid tag, pressed event, etc. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Then you can set up the colors as a constant set in the Values folder and boom! Solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are referring to.  Mono for Android does not ship any NinePatch images.  Mono for Android simply provides a thin binding over the Java API, it does not do anything custom.

Maybe it is triggered by changing your Android target framework?

Comment: I did try going this way, but Xamarin do not give any solutions to the problem. I know the binding should be there, but where and how do I even start??? Thankfully I found my answer. Thank you for posting!